# Background image covering background color on footer

Tags: html, css

Recently, I have been working on a simple website for a small landscaping business as my first test starting as a web developer. Aware of my small amount of skills, the client does not care much for the site to be insanely detailed; he just wants his information to be accessible on the Internet since he isn't confident in his ability to manage social media himself.

I've run into a somewhat common problem from what I've seen, but every answer I try doesn't seem to work out. The problem is, while creating a sample/template with googled images and sample text to form a layout, my background image is covering the background color assigned to the footer, which I don't want. Can someone help me with this?

P.S. I'm aware there are a LOT of things that aren't finished in this code and I believe that I've seen most of them (ex. link targets and urls), but feel free to point them out so I can make note of all of them

```css
body, html {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url("../Images/firepit.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#Logo {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green */
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#Navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding: 10px;
}

#Navigation li {
  display: inline; 
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#Navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#Wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 3.5%;
}

footer {
  background-color: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green */
}

footer p {
  float: left; 
}

footer ul {
  float: right; 
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Woodrow Lawn and Turf</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<!-- DEVELOPER NOTES -->
  <!--

    - Keywords and description meta are still subject to change by the client.
    - Make sure to add correct target attributes and file paths to the nav links.
    - All images used in this mockup are subject to copyright currently.
    - Make sure to add alternate font families to the font-family style.

  -->
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="Logo">Woodrow Lawn and Turf</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul id="Navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Lawn Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Dirt Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Flower Bed Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Patio Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Firepit Stuff</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#">Commercial and Business Stuff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <h1 id="Greeting">Welcome!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Footer">
    <footer>
      <p id="Copyright">&copy; Copyright Woodrow Lawn and Turf LLC 2017</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Contact:</li>
        <li>(999)999-9999</li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li>stuffcompany@comp.net</li>      
      </ul>
    </footer>
  </div>
  

 

 
</body>
  
  
  









</html>
```

Comment: Also to let you guys know running the code snippet doesn't look to well for some reason, it may be the extra message at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code.

```
footer::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

You're floating the content of `footer`, therefore removing them from the flow of the document.

The above code will clear the floats.

Comment: Thank you for the help Tania! As you can tell, I'm not exactly an expert at what I'm doing, but I just need to keep on building knowledge to get where I want to be as a web developer. I know stackoverflow tells me to avoid comments like this, but I don't know any other way to provide feedback and let you know that this really did help me - a checkmark really isn't enough.

Comment: @XavierCheyne Absolutely, you're welcome! I think such a comment is perfect, especially after accepting an answer. Based on your code, you still have much to learn, but don't ever be discouraged by aggressive comments on the internet. I would recommend reading [Interneting is Hard](https://internetingishard.com/) to get your fundamentals down,  [then come visit me](https://www.taniarascia.com/) once you reach an intermediate level. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the awesome power of flex-box!

```
footer {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #064501; /* Dark Woodrow Green */
  height:auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

footer li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First pull the background stuff from the body, html rule set (in the CSS) and make a rule set for body only.

Then add a clearfix that can be used to prevent elements from collapsing.

Use the developing tools in your browser to inspect html elements and the CSS. If you point at the element source code in the developers tools and the element is not highlighted, it is most likely collapsing. Place a div with the class clearfix at the end of the element to fix it.

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/recipes/images/8/85/Firepit.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140404181547");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#Logo {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #064501;
  /* Dark Woodrow Green */
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#Navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding: 10px;
}

#Navigation li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#Navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

#Wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 3.5%;
}

#Footer,
footer {
  background-color: #064501;  /* Dark Woodrow Green */
}

footer p {
  float: left;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden
}

footer ul {
  float: right;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="Logo">Woodrow Lawn and Turf</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul id="Navigation">
      <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Lawn Stuff</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Dirt Stuff</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Flower Bed Stuff</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Patio Stuff</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Firepit Stuff</a></li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Commercial and Business Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="Wrapper">
  <h1 id="Greeting">Welcome!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
    non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
    non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="Footer">
  <footer>
    <p id="Copyright">&copy; Copyright Woodrow Lawn and Turf LLC 2017</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Contact:</li>
      <li>(999)999-9999</li>
      <li>|</li>
      <li>stuffcompany@comp.net</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </footer>
</div>
```